# Storing strings dynamically in a linked list

Tags: c, string, dynamic, linked-list, arrays

I want to create a linked list in C in which the user can input strings which will be stored as nodes in the list. This is my node structure:

```
typdef struct NODE {
    char word[50];
    struct NODE* next;
} node;
```

From my main method I want to prompt the user to enter a strings and subsequently call a method that adds the string to the linked list (but does not include any characters following a space), and do that repeatedly until the user enters a specific string which terminates the process, so in my main method I have:

```
void main(){
    node* fullList = NULL;
    char stopString[5];
    sprintf(stopString, "stop"); 
    char string[50];
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    scanf("%[^ ]s", string);
    while (strcmp(string, stopString) != 0) {
         addToLinkedList(fullList, string);   
         printf("Enter a word: ");
         scanf("%[^ ]s", string);
    }
}
```

This is my addition method:

```
void addToLinkedList(node* list, char str[]) {
    node* freeSpot;
    node* newNode;

    freeSpot = list;
    if (list == NULL){
            freeSpot = freeSpot->next;
    }

    newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    newNode->word = str;
    //strcpy(nweNode->next, str);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    freeSpot->next = newNode;
```

}

BUT I get an error:

```
"incompatible types when assigning to type âchar[256]â from type âchar *â"
```

and if I replace "newNode->word = str;" with the piece of code commented out below, I get:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of âstrcpyâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h:128:14: note: expected âchar * __restrict__â but argument is of type
âstruct NODE *â
```

I'm pretty stuck at this point, I'm not sure how to implement this successfully; any suggestions?

Comment: and `if (list == NULL){` --> `while(freeSpot->next != NULL){`

Comment: for scanf you don't need the extra `s`, this is fine `scanf("%s", string);` `%s` stops reading after a space character is read. Also note that since you are not allocating new memory for your string inputs, all strings in the list will contain the same value

Comment: `void addToLinkedList(node* list, char str[]) {`  --> `void addToLinkedList(node** list, char str[]) {`

Comment: and `if(*list == NULL) { *list = newNode;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```
newNode->word = str;
```

And add:

```
strcpy(nweNode->word, str);
```

You are copying to the member word of the current node, not to the next node.

You should check that `str` is not longer than (50-1) before copying.

Comment: Wow, thanks, can't believe I didn't catch such a silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to the commented line. Have you saved your file after commenting this out? Have you cleaned the project?
Anyway, this line: `newNode->word = str;` is going to cause troubles as well. Use strcpy instead. You want to copy string, not the pointer.